# Linux device driver for a Smart Card IC module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a smart card IC module, and I want to create a Linux device driver for it. This module is using SPI as the controlling line and has an interrupt line to indicate whether a card is ready. I know how to create a SPI device in Linux kernel and how to read data in the kernel when the interruption happens. But I have no idea on how to transfer the data to the user space (maybe need to create a device node for it), and how to give the user space a interruption to notify it. Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: Check existing frameworks, no need to reinvent a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about this is by creating a `devfs` entry and then having the interested process open that device and receive asynchronous notification from the device driver using `fasync`.

Once you have the notification in user space you can notify other interested processes by any means you deem fit.

I am writing a small trimmed down example illustrating this feature.

### On the driver side

```
/* Appropriate headers */

static int myfasync(int fd, struct file *fp, int on);
static struct fasync_struct *fasyncQueue;

static struct file_operations fops =
{
     .open = charDriverOpen,
     .release = charDriverClose,
     .read = charDriverRead,
     .write = charDriverWrite,
     .unlocked_ioctl = charDriverCtrl,
     // This will be called when the FASYNC flag is set
     .fasync = myfasync,
};

static int __init charDriverEntry()
{
      // Appropriate init for the driver
      // Nothing specific needs to be done here with respect to
      // fasync feature.
 }

static int myfasync(int fd, struct file *fp, int on)
{
      // Register the process pointed to by fp to the list
      // of processes to be notified when any event occurs
      return fasync_helper(fd, fp, 1, &fasyncQueue);
}

// Now to the part where we want to notify the processes listed
// in fasyncQueue when something happens. Here in this example I had
// implemented the timer. Not getting in to the details of timer func
// here
static void send_signal_timerfn(unsigned long data)
{
       ...
       printk(KERN_INFO "timer expired \n");

       kill_fasync(&fasyncQueue, SIGIO, POLL_OUT);
       ...
}
```

### On the user land process side

```
void my_notifier(int signo, siginfo_t *sigInfo, void *data)
{
        printf("Signal received from the driver expected %d got %d \n",SIGIO,signo);
}

int main()
{
       struct sigaction signalInfo;
       int flagInfo;

       signalInfo.sa_sigaction = my_notifier;
       signalInfo.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
       sigemptyset(&signalInfo.sa_mask);

       sigaction(SIGIO, &signalInfo, NULL);


       int fp,i;
       fp = open("/dev/myCharDevice",O_RDWR);
       if (fp<0)
               printf("Failed to open\n");

       /*New we will own the device so that we can get the signal from the device*/
       // Own the process
       fcntl(fp, F_SETOWN, getpid());
       flagInfo = fcntl(fp, F_GETFL);
       // Set the FASYNC flag this triggers the fasync fops 
       fcntl(fp, F_SETFL, flagInfo|FASYNC);
       ...
}
```

Hope this clears things up.
For more detailed reading I suggest you read [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch05s04.html)